# Magento 2 duplicate product entry in default store view

Tags: products, store-view, magento2.2.4, duplicate

In my magento2 store I only have one single store assigned to the default view and all the products in were in "all store view". So the store view column in the csv was blank.
[image]

But somehow someone changed the store view to default while editing the products and now we ended up with products with same sku but in a different view with different details. CSV looks like below:

[image]

Now, for these reason..everytime we put in a special price in the advanced pricing - we have to put that in both the views which is causing human error and costing time.

I tried to delete only the default store view sku via csv and both admin panel. From the admin panel it deletes the entire product - having to recreate that again. From CSV it shows success but doesn't have any impact at all.

As we now have many products like these are products customers have already placed an order for - I was wondering if someone can give me an idea on how to delete only the products in default store view without having to delete the entire product.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this issue resloved? I am facing the same issue. Could you please share what did you do to resolve this issue?

Comment: 0Down voteaccept

from memory it was for store view..people were adding the sane product under different store views..so we fixed that via csv bulk edit..

Answer (score 0):

from memory it was for store view..people were adding the sane product under different store views..so we fixed that via csv bulk edit..

Comment: Add this as a comment under the other guys post so he can be notified